# I cannot get Powershell 2.0 to move a file from one path to another

Tags: powershell-2.0, move

I need to make changes to to the following Powershell script, but am having a dickens of a time getting the resulting files to write to a different path...let's call it `$destPath`.

Consider:

`Get-ChildItem $sourcePath | % { [system.io.file]::Move($_.fullname, ($_.FullName -replace '\[|\]|-|,|\(|\)', '') ) }`

Based on my understanding of `move` syntax, `$_.fullname` is my original file, and `$_.FullName -replace...` is the NEW filename. Hoever, when I try to use `$destPath.FullName -replace` I get an error that an empty filename is not legal. Obviously, Powershell is not recognizing that as a valid pathname for the `move` command.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not mention $destPath in context - maybe you did not define the variable $destPath at all? It is quite unlikely but just trying to narrow things down.

Another way to make this work:

Rename child-items first at original location. Then move them.

```
get-childitem *.txt | rename-item -newname {$_.name -replace 'o','O'}

get-childitem *.txt | % {move-item -path $_.fullname -destination .\Test-files}
```

But I prefer your one liner:)

Comment: Yes, I did define $destPath...that was the first thing I checked. :)  But thnaks for the reminder; you have no idea how many times it's something as simple that's the issue. I'll likely split it into two lines just because I can't figure out why the single line solution isn't working for me...

Comment: Dear @dwwilson66 if you think it makes sense can you mark it as "answer"? :)